# How to move through an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, infinite-loop

I need to move an index though an array to put an random array in order. Here is my code.

```
void insertNumber(int randomNum, int data[], int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; randomNum > data[i] && i <= size - 2; i++)
    {

    }

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                data[i+1] = data [i];
            } 
    data[i] = randomNum;
}
```

Thank you for your time. It is an infinite loop I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: cant you use the build in sort function? or the swap one?

Comment: @elyashiv It looks like Kayla might be implementing a bubble-sort by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          data[i+1] = data [i];
      }
```

This looks like it's going to overwrite everything from `data[0]` to `data[9]` with `data[0]`.  I'm not sure if that's what you're trying to accomplish.

Also,

```
data[i] = randomNum;
```

is going to assign randomNum to `data[10]` regardless of order. Perhaps we could get some more clarification on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Yes sorry I was unclear. I am trying to progress an index though an array and maintain order. So im trying to insert a random number and put it in the right place.